# Why I failed to get two structure address?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a structure like:

```
typedef struct {
    int index;
    float value;
    ...
} DAT;
```

I hope to find the address of structrue with min and max value, which are used for other purposes(Here I have simplified the structure, because I have other information in the DAT, so I have to get the whole structure)

```
void FindMinMax (DAT *, int, DAT *, DAT *);
void main () {
    DAT *L = NULL;
    DAT *min = NULL, *max = NULL;

    L = (DAT *) malloc(5 * sizeof(DAT));
    FindMinMax(L, 5, min, max);
}

void FindMinMax(DAT *L, int N, DAT *min, DAT *max) {
    int i;

    for (...) {
    ...
    /* for example */
    min = L + 1;
    max = L + 2;
    }
}
```

Why I failed to get min = L + 1, max = L + 2 in main function?

Comment: Your example is too simplified. Please post a [mcve], ephasis on __Complete__.

Comment: A double pointer is required to update the caller's pointer on the function side.

Comment: Thanks n.m., yes, it duplicate what you have referred.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I I understood your question well, but you probably want this:

```
void main () {
    DAT *L = NULL;
    DAT *min = NULL, *max = NULL;

    L = malloc(5 * sizeof(DAT));    // cast is not required
    FindMinMax(L, 5, &min, &max);
}

void FindMinMax(DAT *L, int N, DAT **min, DAT **max) {
    int i;

    for (...) {
    ...
    /* for example */
    *min = L + 1;
    *max = L + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael